# Why are telomeres needed to allow DNA replication at the ends of linear chromosomes?

Tags: dna-replication, telomere

I’m reading *Molecular Biology of the Cell* by Alberts et. Al and at one point the authors mention the following:

> We saw earlier that synthesis of the lagging strand at a replication
> fork must occur discontinuously through a backstitching mechanism that
> produces short DNA fragments. This mechanism encounters a special
> problem when the replication fork reaches an end of a linear
> chromosome. **The final RNA primer synthesized on the lagging-strand
> template cannot be replaced by DNA because there is no 3ʹ-OH end
> available for the repair polymerase**. Without a mechanism to deal with
> this problem, DNA would be lost from the ends of all chromosomes each
> time a cell divides [emphasis mine].

They use this explanation as a motivation for why telomeres are needed. But I don’t quite understand it. Below is a diagram that they show earlier. It seems to me like the process shown can just as easily be done at the ends of chromosomes. In particular, if we imagine that the left-most primer has no DNA following it, it seems to me like polymerase can just do what it normally does to replicate the DNA until the end is reached. Where’s the problem?
[image]

Comment: How is the 3’ end of the orange strand replicated?

Comment: @canadianer I see. But what is meant by "there is no 3ʹ-OH end available for the repair polymerase"?

Comment: It means that DNA polymerase only extends existing chains and doesn’t create new chains *de novo*. In other words, it needs a primer.

Comment: @canadianer right but why is there no 3’-OH end available?

Comment: This just means that because the final part of the 'reading' is in the 3'-OH to 5'-OH direction (R to L in the orange lagging strand), the last available component for synthesis of an RNA primer by the DNA primase is from that latter 5'-OH towards the 3'-OH end of the strand.  So, the final 3'-OH component of that strand cannot be synthesised: there is no 5'-OH component to its right in the diagram. Telomeres perform other functions; nature is fantastically efficient. The whole thing is an immensely beautiful wave (interference) dynamic in 3-D, wrapped around the tetrahedral form of histones.

Comment: @jeremiah but why can another primer not be added right at the 3'-OH end (at the rightmost end of the lagging strand template)?

Comment: This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NS0jBPurWQ answered my question

Comment: The final 3'-OH component cannot be 'read' due to the absence of a further 5'-OH to its right: the requisite directional sense for the initiation of a further primer is absent. I'm glad you found the video -- that's the point.

Comment: And yes, the video clarifies it all very nicely.  The key information is the absence of the 3'-OH at the correct end of the Okazaki fragment (right in the video), to prime further DNA synthesis.  So, thank you for that: I'm a wanderer too.